# Django Python login to external web site, ajax, or urlllib

Tags: python, ajax, django, authentication, external

I'm developing a website in Django and I want that when the user hits the Login button, it both authenticates him in my website and in ide.cigiden.cl.
Authentication in my website is working properly using django-registration-redux, but the external one isn't.

I know the credentials for ide.cigiden.cl and it's not a problem for me to do it. But I need to know how to do it. I've tried a lot of answers in this site, with urllib, urllib2, etc.
I'm in contact with the developer of ide.cigiden.cl right now, he did it in Django. So I could actually ask him to write some code in views.py or other file to help me authenticate.

The url where you login is ide.cigiden.cl/account/login/
He also told me maybe trying with ide.cigiden.cl/account/ajax_login might work.

In the file views.py of his project he has the following code:

```
def ajax_login(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponse(
            content="ajax login requires HTTP POST",
            status=405,
            mimetype="text/plain"
        )
    form = AjaxLoginForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is None or not user.is_active:
            return HttpResponse(
            content="bad credentials or disabled user",
            status=400,
            mimetype="text/plain"
        )
        else:
            login(request, user)
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
        return HttpResponse(
            content="successful login",
            status=200,
            mimetype="text/plain"
        )
    else:
    return HttpResponse(
        "The form you submitted doesn't look like a username/password combo.",
        mimetype="text/plain",
        status=400)
```

That's it. I would highly appreciate some help! 
I'm not that good at javascript so if I can get it done using python it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

1. User hits Login
2. Authenticate him on your site
3. Redirect him to ide.cigiden.cl (using JS) with a unique token
4. Automatically authenticate user on ide.cigiden.cl
5. Redirect back to your site

**Notes**:

When a user is authenticated, a cookie is set on his browser. When user hits Login button on your site, he will be authenticated on your site and only your site's cookie will be saved on his browser. He will also need auth cookie from ide.cigiden.cl to be authenticated there. That is why you'll need to redirect.